# Row grouping and its subTotal for multiple level in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

[Example as I needed pics is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ffwt.png)I want to group multiple columns and also display the sub totals of each groups respectively using rowGroup extension or any other alternative

I have got the code for multiple RowGrouping But I want to find its summation or Average(ie, Any Aggregate Function). the code which I got is  as below

```
datatable = container.find('.dataTable').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
        var last = null;
        var columns = x11;
        for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {
        var colNo = columns[c]; 
        api.column(colNo, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
            console.log("group drawcallback",group);
            if (last !== group) {
                $(rows).eq(i).before(
                    '<tr class="group group-start"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                );
                last = group;
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Can anybody help plz.

Comment: As you can see a screenshot attached, In that format I want the result. ie, I want to rowgroup the data multiple time and that multiple times I want to apply aggregate function to each rowgrouped data and the aggregate result must be displayed accordingly. The tools I used is Jquery and datatable